# How to redirect the load of .so lib in Android using Xposed?

Tags: android, xposed, xposed-framework

I have an app that contains a lib (for example, "test.so") and I want to redirect the load of that .so to another "test.so" which is modified by me, I tried everthing using Xposed like:

```
public class xposed implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (lpparam.packageName.equals("package")) {
            findAndHookMethod("java.lang.System", lpparam.classLoader, "loadLibrary", String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param){
                    XposedBridge.log("(before) Loaded library: " + param.args[0]);
                    if (param.args[0].toString().equals("test")){
                        System.load("/data/data/package/modified_test.so");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes, I searched on Google and I found this: [System.loadlibrary hook crash](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/issues/87#issuecomment-188748697) but when I want to hook into Runtime like rovo said it doesn't do nothing. Someone know any solution?

(Please don't tell me about changing the lib into .apk because if I want that I didn't asking this xD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can not work because you are hooking the wrong method.

`System.loadlibrary` expects as parameter the library name without file path, without prepended `lib` and without file extension. Therefore if you replace the parameter with `"/data/data/package/modified_test.so"` as shown in your example the library loading will not work.

I assume you may have more luck if you hook the method that is responsible for mapping the library name to the actual library file: `System.mapLibraryName(String)`.
You can see how it is used in [Runtime.loadLibrary(String, ClassLoader)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/41d00b744b7772f9302fdb94dddadb165b951220/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Runtime.java#354)

To do so use an `afterHookedMethod`, check the result value and overwrite the return value with the path to your modified library.

Comment: Ok, I will test it. Thanks :).

Comment: Yea but I have a bit problem, what happen if the APK contains more libs? How can I do it?

Comment: Instead of on an `XC_MethodHook` use an `XC_MethodReplacement`. If a call for your to-.be-replaced library is coming is modify it and then call the original method with the modified parameter. For libraries you don't care directly call the original method.

Comment: Because you don't read or test what the method you hook is supposed to do. `mapLibraryName('test')` -> returns `libtest.so`. Second as a Java developer you should know that you NEVER EVER use `==` for comparing Strings. Use `equals`.